# Circle mask acts like rectangle

Tags: mask, haxe, openfl

I'm trying to draw an object masked with a circle, but the mask applied is more like a circle's bounding rectangle

I tried using circle drawn with drawCircle method:

```
private function squareToRound(ability:MovieClip):MovieClip
{
    var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var newAbility:MovieClip = ability;
    var newMask:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    newAbility.width = 43;
    newAbility.height = 43;
    newMask.x = newAbility.x + newAbility.width / 2;
    newMask.y = newAbility.y + newAbility.height / 2;

    container.addChild(newAbility);
    newMask.graphics.beginFill();
    newMask.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 8);
    newMask.graphics.endFill();
    container.addChild(newMask);

    newAbility.mask = newMask;
    return container;
}
```

... and as an asset from SWF:

```
private function squareToRound(ability:MovieClip):MovieClip
{
    var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var newAbility:MovieClip = ability;
    var newMask:MovieClip = new CircleAbilityMask();

    newAbility.width = 43;
    newAbility.height = 43;
    newMask.x = newAbility.x + newAbility.width / 2;
    newMask.y = newAbility.y + newAbility.height / 2;

    container.addChild(newAbility);
    container.addChild(newMask);

    newAbility.mask = newMask;
    return container;
}
```

The results are equal.

I checked what the mask looks like by commenting "newAbility.mask = newMask;" line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be resolved in the current OpenFL release:

https://github.com/openfl/openfl/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#650-11102017

You can also use Cairo (on native platforms) or Canvas (on HTML5) for smoother/better masking support:

```
openfl test html5 -Dcanvas
openfl test windows -Dcairo
```

These are also used when you `bitmapData.draw`, `sprite.cacheAsBitmap = true` or other APIs that trigger a software render rather than GL.

Comment: Are there any ways to mask an object with a custom shape while targeting neko? Updating OpenFl will lead to incompatibility with SWF library

Comment: The latest OpenFL has SWF support built-in, no SWF library required

Comment: Well, could you please explain me, how to use SWF asset container in OpenFL 6.0+. I remembered I was trying to use it with <library> tag more than half a year ago, but the compiler seemed to totally ignore it if the SWF path was correct, so I switched to swf lib after downgrading openfl and lime

Comment: Look at the "NyanCat" sample (`openfl create NyanCat`) or try the "Using SWF Assets" tutorial http://www.openfl.org/learn/tutorials/using-swf-assets/

Comment: I know it.
I need the example of the new ways of SWF usage since 6.0
If there are no other ways, well, as I said, it wont work. Library tag is completely ignored when does not contain any errors

Comment: OK, I get it, I'll just ask another question